# Calculating distance for each point along line in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, line, network, nodes

I have a polyline(Roads network) and points(Nodes) recorded along the line. I would like to calculate the distance for each point along the line in ArcGIS 10.1. Result will added in a new column and distance should be like Node 1 to - Node 2, Node 3, Node 4, Node 5....., Node 2 to - Node 1, Node 3, Node 4.....

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please write all your question as text rather than including some of it as a picture which is a tactic some students use to try and hide the questions they ask here from their professors.  I would also urge you to read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th because it appears that you have created a new account to try and circumvent a question ban.  As you will read, creating a new account and continuing to ask the same question risks deepening the ban.

Comment: First understand the differences between - NODE TO NODE DISTANCES and DISTANCES BETWEEN EACH NODES TO EVERY NODES. If you think that you have two line intersecting each other and creating 5 nodes like 'X' then i want to calculate the distances from Node 1 to Node 2, Node 3, Node 4 and Node 5 along those lines.

Answer (score 2):

Use Tool **Split Line at Point**. More information about below URL:

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/split-line-at-point.htm

After Splitting the lines at point. Go Load the newly created Feature class in ArcMap, and then you may add a field in the feature class **distance**. Then using Calculate Geometry tool, generate the distance of each line which are from one node to other.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  But I want to calculate the distance from each point to every point along the line. Suppose I have 6 nodes and 6 line. Distance  from Node-4 to Node-2 will be  (Node-4 to Node-1) + (Node-1 to Node-3) + (Node-3 to Node-2). I want to calculate the distance in that fashion. Notable think is the distance between Node 1 to Node 6 have 2 routes, i.e. one from Node -1 to via Node-3, Node-5, Node-6 and other is from Node-1 to Node-3 and Node-6. For those cases want the shortest distance ( or both).

Comment: Sir please first understand the differences between - NODE TO NODE DISTANCES and DISTANCES BETWEEN EACH NODES TO EVERY NODES. If you think that you have two line intersecting each other and creating 5 nodes like 'X' then i want to calculate the distances from Node 1 to Node 2, Node 3, Node 4 and Node 5 along those lines.